# Using R on Spotfire, How to retrieve a value by searching for closest values in a look-up table?

Tags: r, database, spotfire

A very small sample of two existing tables exist in spotfire:

Main Table

```
Road Easting Northing
M1   456252  278173
M1   443281  389200
M1   447205  335640
M1   500425  233986
```

Lookup Table

```
CP     Easting  Northing
8219   448325   388413
36004  457081   275396
81549  500244   234300
56005  447134   336976
73366  446865   330080
73039  505000   223710
```

Goal

This will be the result with a new column pointing to the nearest CP.

```
Road Easting Northing CP
M1   456252  278173   36004
M1   443281  389200   8219
M1   447205  335640   56005
M1   500425  233986   81549
```

Is there a formula or R scriopt that would be able to return this Lookup column?

I am basically trying to search for the nearest values of the Eastings and Northings in the first table in the second table. Then by selecting the nearest northings and eastings looking up the CP (which is the unique ID).

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this?

Comment: If this is an exact matching, you are looking for `merge`. Something like `merge(df1, df2, by=c("Easting", "Northing"))`

Comment: do you want to use R specifically? I only ask because in spotfire, this is easily accomplished without R

Comment: scsimon - I just want to be able to match them, so if it can be done without  the use of R that would be great!

Comment: The CP coordinates are different to the different road coordinates, so no not an exact match. I need to find the closest CP coordinate so that I can match the locations on the road to that CP.

Comment: no worries @kc8g15 i'll work something up for you in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Would this code work?

```
whichindex <- data.frame(
                    (sapply(main$Easting, function(x) which.min(abs(x - lookup$Easting)))),
                    (sapply(main$Northing, function(y) which.min(abs(y - lookup$Northing))))
                )
output <- cbind(main,whichindex)
```